# Typescript react error: JSX element doesn't have any construct or call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I recently upgraded typescript and I am getting the above error in one of my components.

I have the following code in that component `render` method:

```
render() {
   const Tag = props.link ? 'a' : 'div';
   return (
      <Tag className="dummy"> text </Tag>
   );
}
```

When I return `div` or `a` directly in my code, it works correctly. When I return `Tag` it fails!

EDIT: Open issue in Github: https://www.github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28768

Comment: You can't dynamically construct elements like that. `'a'` isn't a React element, it's a string.

Comment: What about `const Tag = (props) => React.createElement(props.link ? 'a' : 'div', { className: "dummy" }, props.children);` However this is just a simple component that you could initialize outside the class.

Comment: What you are doing in valid JS. I just had a similar issue when updating from TS 3.1.6 to 3.2.1 so it might be an issue with the last TS update...

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28768

Answer (score 1):

Your code is interesting. I tried it out in Codesandbox and it works for me with TypeScript.

I might using different TypeScript version or tsconfig. Or you use tslint.
You can check the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/40rv9qjz9) out here. What is the difference?

I used this code, you can repleace the link to '' and it works that way too.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

interface Props {}

enum TagTypes {
  a = 'a',
  div = 'div'
}

class Hello extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {
    let link = "#";
    const Tag: TagTypes = link ? TagTypes.a : TagTypes.div;
    return (
      <Tag className="dummy" href={link}>
        text
      </Tag>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, rootElement);
```

Comment: `const Tag: any` fixed this error!!

I believe it is expecting a type for Tag. Can you please tell me what would be the type other than `any`? `string` fails

Comment: I made some experiment with the code. It works for me with enum. It is much better than any I think. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Inside render you have declared `const Tag as string`.

Now inside return block, React will search for JSX syntax, here React expect **Tag** as element/class.

If you remove `const Tag = ...` you will get an error saying `Tag is not defined or similar`

Lastly, Datatype is mismatching in your problem statement.